# Building a Xcode project downloaded from GitHub

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, open-source

I am just starting to learn about code and programming apps.

I downloaded Xcode project [source-code](https://github.com/SevenBits/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader) for a mac app that I wish to use from GitHub.

How can I turn that code into an executable application?

The repository readme states 3 steps to build the project. I am done with the first 2 steps, but I don't know how to complete the last one.

Can someone help me understand the difference between an archive build and a run/debug, and how to do them in Xcode?

Comment: What part of the document section [Building from Source](https://github.com/SevenBits/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader#building-from-source)  don't you understand? so we can explain that but in general this question  appears to be too broad

Comment: @Mark is correct - we can't know what you do and don't know. You'll want to break things down in to very small chunks if you want to learn to program on Stack Exchange - here or stack overflow. If you know nothing about programming - starting with Xcode playgrounds and structured lessons might be less painful - but if you love that project - it might be the place for you to start after all.

Comment: Did you install CocoaPods as indicated?

Comment: Yes, I did do that.

Comment: You need to be in the `Mac-Linux-USB-Loader` directory created by `git clone ...` to run `pod install`.

Comment: I completed the pod installation. After that what do I do? What does archive build mean?

Comment: You’ll need to clean up the last edit, please. Or hit someone up in [chat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help menu works great in Xcode. If you search for each term listed in Step 3, the menu items you need will be shown to you in Xcode.

[image]

Running a Mac app is trivial - click the play button in the toolbar - you don’t need any simulator or certificates or setup or choosing a scheme like the image above indicates.

Since you are new, I would also spend time in the Xcode documentation on getting started.

- http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/#/devc8c2a6be1

You will get alerts in the activity area if anything fails - the project you are starting with has made hundreds of decisions in the project file, dozens of which would take me several weeks to digest (spending an hour a day on this alone) and understand at a cursory level. I’m not a full time developer, but I have been compiling and making Mac apps since the late 80s and I still need to read the documents, watch wwdc videos and ask questions online. Good luck and don’t worry if you have lots of work ahead to find and fix any compile errors or if you have start a new project to learn how Xcode works step by step.

Comment: I opened up Mac Linux USB Loader.xcworkspace, but Xcode isn't responding when I press run. It appears to be indexing. I left Xcode open for an hour and it still says indexing at the activity pane

Comment: Yup - I expect you might not get a clean run, but you might once the play button allows you to try running the code. Lots of cocoa pod dependencies may take some time (dozens of minutes or more) to compile for you.

Comment: Ok I finally was able to run, but I got 2 errors. They are about the signing certificate. One of them was about adding a developer account to Xcode which is no problem, but the other says "No signing certificate 'Mac Development' found". How do I fix the second error?

Comment: @InterestedLearner AppleStackExchange doesn't work like this. Please first read the Xcode Help, then search ASE or Google for similar error messages *("No signing certificate 'Mac Development' found")* and **then** ask a follow-up question **not** in the comments but as a **new** question if you haven't found a suitable answer here or elsewhere.